# Adding dictionary indexes through a function

Tags: python

I've been trying on how to add a new index in a dictionary using a for loop.
I want to keep adding indexes with a for loop each time I enter the value, the 'index' through a function.

So the dictionary just keep growing.

For example:

My dictionary has it's values as lists, and to add values to that list, I can use
    dictionary[index].append(value)

In a function:

```
dicc = {'index':[]}

def addStuff(i = '', v = ''):    
    for i in dicc:
        dicc[i].append(v) #adds values to the list
    return
```

but it doesn't occurs me adding indexes

I've been trying, and it seems it just doesn't come to mind, yet.
So I would want to know what ways there are to keep dictionary's indexes growing through a function.
Maybe and probably it's something easy to do, but right now I'm sort of blocked, and yes I've been trying, ... this is why I came here. 
Thanks in advance. 
:)

Comment: Err, what? Why would you need to loop through the dictionary to do any of this? Also, what isn't working ("it doesn't occurs me adding indexes" is grossly useless)?

Comment: I want to make some sort of a graph, simulate one using dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as delnan noticed, you seem to have got a little confused in your `addStuff` function.  I'm guessing you want it to add an item `v` to the list in the dictionary with key `i`. However, what your function actually does is add item `v` to every list in the dictionary regardless of what key it has.  The value `i` you pass to the function is completely ignored because it is immediately overwritten by the loop variable.

Suppose `dicc` contains `{'index': [1, 8], 'someOtherIndex': [4, 11]}`.  If we were to call `addStuff('index', 23)`, or `addStuff('someOtherIndex', 23)`, or even
`addStuff('supercalifragilisticexpialidocious', 23)`, we would end up with `dicc` containing `{'index': [1, 8, 23], 'someOtherIndex': [4, 11, 23]}` *in all three cases*.

I'm not sure why you don't just write your `addStuff` function like this:

```
def addStuff(i = '', v = ''):    
    dicc[i].append(v)
```

I'm guessing that your next problem is that this approach doesn't work if the value of `i` isn't a key in the dictionary.  In that case you'd want the function to automatically create an empty list for that key :

```
def addStuff(i = '', v = ''):    
    if i not in dicc:
        dicc[i] = []
    dicc[i].append(v)
```

Comment: This really helped me in what I wanted to do.  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the .iteritems(), .iterkeys, and .itervalues() functions.

```
for key in dicc.iterkeys():
    print key # A key

for key in dicc.itervalues():
    key.append(5) # appends 5 to the value

for (key, value) in dicc.iteritems():
    pass # I have both the key and the value
```

Comment: I could have already a dictionary with predefined keys and values like, 'dicc = {'S':[], 'A':[], 'D':[]}', and make a function that add values to the lists with a for loop like, 
'
def add(v = ''):
    for i in dicc: 
        dicc[i].append(v)
    return
'
I want to do the same but with adding the keys instead of the list values.

Answer (score 0):

```
dicc = {'a':[1]}

def addStuff(keys, vals):
    for key,val in zip(keys,vals):
        if key not in dicc:
            dicc[key] = [val]
        else:
            dicc[key].append(val) #adds values to the list

addStuff('a', '2')
addStuff(['b', 'a'], ['3', 'blah'])
print dicc
# {'a': [1, '2', 'blah'], 'b': ['3']}
```